# Mongoose, how do I join to collections using populate?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

**First Schema:**

```
const ProviderSchema =  new mongoose.Schema({
    provName    : { type: String, index: true }
});
module.exports = mongoose.model('provider', ProviderSchema);
```

**Second Schema:**

```
const WebProviderSchema =  new mongoose.Schema({
    userId      : { type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'users'},
    providerId  : { type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'providers'}
});
module.exports = mongoose.model('webProvider', WebProviderSchema);
```

How do I join these two schemas?

So far if I do the following, I only get data from the second schema:

```
webProvider
            .find({userId : '23423df234434bc956'})
            .populate("providers")
            .exec( function (error, listData) {
                  console.log(listData);
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To populate you should use local field `providerId`. Should be `.populate("providerId")` instead of `.populate("providers")`.

```
webProvider.find({userId : '23423df234434bc956'})
           .populate("providerId")
           .exec( function (error, listData) {
               console.log(listData);
           });
```

To populate multiple field can use like :

```
.populate("providerId userId")
```

**or**

```
.populate("providerId")
.populate("userId")
```

Comment: @JuanGonzales you can accept any answer that you like its up to you. but my answer was posted before others answer .I mentioned because you noticed another answer was first. however its ok  :) .